# How to avoid duplicate object in array and only update the item quantity in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm trying to find a way to remove duplicate object from my `array` list and update the item quantity property instead. I'm pushing the objects to my `sharedService`.

item component -- but this only updates the quantity by 1 but still pushes the same object in the array. Not sure if the `if()` should be in the `addToBasket()` or in the `SharedService` but pretty sure the `if()` statement is wrong.

How can I push unique object into my array and only update the quantity when you add the same object/item?

```
addToBasket() {
let items = {
  id: '123',
  quantity: 1
};

if (items) {
  items.quantity = parseInt(items.quantity) + 1;
} else {
  this.basketArr = {
    id: items.name,
    quantity: items.quantity
  }
}
 this.sharedService.itemCollection(items);
}
```

My `SharedService` so far is only holding the `array` objects

```
itemCollection(id) {
  this.itemArr.push(id);
  console.log(this.itemArr);
}
```

Desired result should look like value `2` is an updated quantity.

```
[{ id: '123, quantity: 2 }]
```

instead of --

```
[
 { id: '123, quantity: 2 },
 { id: '123, quantity: 2 }
]
```

[Plnkr Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ui79vZvUc2wAf1ue1jb?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether the new item exists before push it to Array.

```
itemCollection(id) {
  // check whether id exists
  var index = this.itemArr.findIndex(item => item.id === id.id);

  if (index > -1) {
    // check quantity to determin whether replace the exist one or not
    if (id.quantity === this.itemArr[index].quantity) {
      return;
    } else {
      // update quantity for the exist one
      this.itemArr[index].quantity = id.quantity;
    }
  } else {
    // add the new item which dosen't exist
    this.itemArr.push(id);
  }

  console.log(this.itemArr); 
}
```

do all things in service

```
itemCollection(id) {
  // check id only
  var index = this.itemArr.findIndex(item => item.id === id.id);

  if (index > -1) {
    this.itemArr[index].quantity = this.itemArr[index].quantity + 1;
  } else {
    this.itemArr.push(id);
  }

  console.log(this.itemArr); 
}
```

Comment: @MrNew since in `addToBasket`, `quantity` will always be 2, so I give the suggest for check `id` only. You can check both `id` and `quantity` in `Array.findIndex`, or just move the increment of `quantity` to be done in service.

Comment: somehow it doesn't add new/different object into the array, its just updating the quantity of whatever object in the array. Also can you edit the code above, code block seems to be broken.

Comment: @MrNew clode block updated. BTW, which one do you prefer?

Comment: well the 2nd one seems to be a lot easier to read as it has less `if()` conditions. Though first one doesn't update the `quantity`

Comment: Sorry meant to say first code, in case you missed that bit.

Comment: @MrNew yep,  Comparing json object deeply always make problem to be somekind complex. Let's discuss detilas of your problem here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141690/pengyyyyyy

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
https://plnkr.co/edit/2oR6vA5hJcRbzR0dtNE5?p=preview

Changed your service part to this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedServiceService {
  public itemArr: any = [];
  constructor() { }

  itemCollection(id) {
    var obj=this.checkUniqueCondition(id);
    console.log(this.itemArr);
  }

  checkUniqueCondition(id){
    if(this.itemArr.length>0){
    for(var a in this.itemArr){
      if(this.itemArr[a].id==id.id){
        this.itemArr[a].quantity=this.itemArr[a].quantity+id.quantity;
        return this.itemArr[a];
      }else{
        console.log("in else");
        this.itemArr.push(id);
      }
    }
  }else{
    this.itemArr.push(id);
  }

}
```

If the match is found it will add in existing object.

```
this.itemArr[a].quantity=this.itemArr[a].quantity+id.quantity;
```

Comment: Thanks this works :) will accept it but will be using @Pengyy's 2nd code block asnwer.

Comment: You can +1 it :p

Comment: Oh I thought I did, will do it again :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
itemCollection(item) {
  let itemSearch = this.itemArr.filter(function(value){
    if(item.id == value.id)
      return value;
  })

  if( itemSearch.length == 0 )
  {
    this.itemArr.push(item);
  }
  else
  {
    let index = this.itemArr.indexOf(itemSearch[0]);
    this.itemArr[index].quantity = item.quantity;
  }
  console.log(this.itemArr); }
```